# Android : holder.getSurface() always return null

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview, surfaceholder

My view is a bunch of normal widget and a surfaceview. I don't know why after I get `surfaceholder` of SurfaceView and use `getSurface()` again on holder, I will always return null.

Here is my example code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        this.holder = surface.getHolder();

         if (holder.getSurface().isValid()){  // get surface again
             Log.i("Notice","Surface holder is valid");
         }
         else
             Log.i("Notice","Surface holder ISNOT valid");  //Always receive this
        }
```

When I see Android document for `getSurface()` method.  This is how it say:

> Direct access to the surface object. The Surface may not always be
>   available -- for example when using a SurfaceView the holder's Surface
>   is not created until the view has been attached to the window manager
>   and performed a layout in order to determine the dimensions and screen
>   position of the Surface. You will thus usually need to implement
>   Callback.surfaceCreated to find out when the Surface is available for
>   use.

I don't understand this so much but I know I have miss something. Please explain for me, and tell me about `Callback.surfaceCreated` means, and how to implement it ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are trying to use surface when it is not available yet. That's alright it is not available at your `Activity.onCreate` or `Activity.onResume` methods because actually surface is placed in separate window behind your Activity window and has own lifecycle.
You need to implement [SurfaceHolder.Callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html) to receive events about `Surface` availability and do drawing from a separate thread. Look at LunarLander project in Android SDK samples folder, it is shown there how to use SurfaceView properly.

Your callback will look something like that:

```
public class MyCallback implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, 
        int width, int height) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // you need to start your drawing thread here
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {  
        // and here you need to stop it
    }
}
```

And than you need to set this callback to SurfaceHolder:

```
surface.getHolder().addCallback(new MyCallback());
```

Answer (score 0):

i found solution, this worked for me, infect error is in choosing correct size , so while using MediaRecorder.setVideoSize() use this method to choose optimal size

```
private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height) {
        Size bigEnough = null;
        int minAreaDiff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Size option : choices) {
            int diff = (width*height)-(option.getWidth()*option.getHeight()) ;
            if (diff >=0 && diff < minAreaDiff &&
                    option.getWidth() <= width &&
                    option.getHeight() <= height) {
                minAreaDiff = diff;
                bigEnough = option;
            }
        }
        if (bigEnough != null) {
            return bigEnough;
        } else {
            Arrays.sort(choices,new CompareSizeByArea());
            return choices[0];
        }

    }
```